# Firebase FCM notifications not displaying

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I created an android app in android studio and I connected it with Firebase. I know it is connected because when the app is open onMessageRecieved is being called and I can see it in the log.

There are similar posts on here, and ive tried everything I could find including:

adding this to the manifest:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
        <!-- Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon is set for incoming notification messages.
     See README() for more. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
        <!-- Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming
             notification message. See README() for more. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/white" />
```

Using this createNotificationChannel() method in the MainActivity OnCreate() and in my class that extends FirebaseMessagingService:

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                    "default_notification_channel_id",
                    "Channel name",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel.setDescription("Channel description");

            // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
            // or other notification behaviors after this
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            if (notificationManager != null) {
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
        }
    }
```

Below Ill add my AndroidManifest and the class extending FirebaseMessagingService, honestly I feel like theres one obvious thing I keep missing but I have been trying to fix this for days with no luck. Let me know if I need to add anything else.

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestApp"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="31" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
        <!-- Set custom default icon. This is used when no icon is set for incoming notification messages.
     See README() for more. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
        <!-- Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming
             notification message. See README() for more. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/white" />

        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


        <activity
            android:name=".RealSettingsActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_real_settings"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.TestApp.NoActionBar" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".WebviewActivity"
            android:exported="false" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    public static final String TAG = "Push-Event";
    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = String.valueOf(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
    public static final String CHANNEL_NAME = "com.example.androidappfortesting";

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        // Check if message contains a Notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            String description = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Title: " + title);
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Description: " + description);
            
            createNotificationChannel();
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel_id")
                    .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
                    .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                    "default_notification_channel_id",
                    "Channel name",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel.setDescription("Channel description");

            // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
            // or other notification behaviors after this
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            if (notificationManager != null) {
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the problem is that you have created a `NotificationChannel` with `default_notification_channel_id`, while in `NotificationCompat.Builder` you use `channel_id`.

So try replacing with:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "default_notification_channel_id")
```